# Why TableLayout components set to the same column do not align?

Tags: android-layout, android-tablelayout

I am quite sure that I am missing something fundamental about TableLayout, but I am unable to figure out it after doing quite some search and reading.
Here is the code:

```
<TableLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TableRow>
        <Button android:layout_column="0" android:text="00" android:visibility="gone"/>
        <Button android:layout_column="1" android:text="01"/>
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow>
        <Button android:layout_column="0"  android:text="10"/>
        <Button android:layout_column="1" android:text="11"/>
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

Here is the result:

[image]

I expected button "01" would be aligned with button "11" because both of them are set to column 1.  Could anyone point out what I am mising?

[Edit]
If the visibility value "gone" of "00" is an issue, why does removing it would make it work as following:

```
<TableLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TableRow>
        <Button
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:text="01" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow>

        <Button
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:text="10" />

        <Button
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:text="11" />
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It's because you set `visibility` `GONE` for *Button* with value *00* so that's why it isn't taking space in *layout*.

Here you can find use of both.

`View.GONE` This view is invisible, and it doesn't take any space for `layout` purposes.

`View.INVISIBLE` This view is invisible, but it still takes up space for `layout` purposes.

So just by changing *visibility* to *invisible* for `Button` with value *00* will work as intended.

```
<TableLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TableRow>

        <Button
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:text="00"
            android:visibility="invisible" />

        <Button
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:text="01" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow>

        <Button
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:text="10" />

        <Button
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:text="11" />
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thank you for trying to help.  In response to your answer, I edited my question because it is impossible to show code and images in a comment.  My primary point is the android:layout_column does not do its work under all circumstances.